# Web API Basic Authentication for Linux CLient

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, basic-authentication

I am New to Web API Authentication. 
I have a requirement to provide Basic authentication for a single method in the API. 
The Client application is in Linux. I was informed that it wont support windows authentication mode.

Need help to identify the correct way to implement this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question needs a lot more details. What is 'Windows authentication mode'? Are you talking about using PAM authentication for Linux? Are you building your own user-password database and authentication users to a WebAPI that way? Are you using ASP.net (even though you're running on Linux)?

Comment: We are just informed that,  credentials will be passed in the header. Currently all the Api is having windows authentication set in web config. We are planning to create our own user-password database authentication for that new method alone.  I have made few updates in the code.  I have enabled Basic authentication in IIS. And overrided OnAuthorize method, where I am implementing the user-password logic. But it always hit windows authentication before hitting my authorization logic.  Here I am compelled to pass windows credentials,  not my db user-paswword.